# Deserialize inner portion of XML into new class instance

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

Given XML in the following (simplified) format:

```
<outer><inner><field1>a</field1><field2>b</field2><field3>c</field3></inner></outer>
```

I'd like to deserialize the `<inner>` element into a class representing that and discard the rest.

```
public class Inner {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    // getters, setters, ctor
}
```

I am using the Jackson `XmlMapper` class to perform the deserialization. If I strip `<outer>` out of the xml string obviously it works.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
// in my scenario the `<inner>` element actually contains fields I don't care about
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Inner inner = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Inner.class);
System.out.println(inner);
// Inner(field1=a, field2=b, field3=c)
```

If I leave the `<outer>` element all of the fields in `inner` are null.

I've tried annotating the `Inner` class with `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "inner")` but that didn't change the output.

I could create a class that represents the `<outer>` element but that seems wasteful. I could probably also create a new string containing just the xml between the `<inner>` elements, but again that feels a bit hacky.

In my case the xml is being broadcast by a separate system that I have no control over, so I can simply amend the xml structure.

Is it possible to deserialize the "inner" xml into a new class instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "inner")` to work as you expect you also need [UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE). E.g.

```
xmlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

I can't say the above is very obvious from the docs.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that feature was the key.